# Read number from text file in C++

Tags: c++, string, loops, int

I am currently writing a program that reads in numbers from a .txt file but I require it to break the loop once it read stop in the file

I know this `while` statement is wrong, but I this is the just of what I am trying to accomplish .

```
while (inFile >> x && x != stop)
{
  //the basic adding up of the numbers
  sum = sum + x;
  cout<<sum<<endl;
  sum = x;
}

if (x == stop)
{
    cout<<"File reading stopped";
}

inFile.close();
return 0;
```

I need the code to stop reading int's as soon as it reads stop within the .txt file.

I know some of the code is completely wrong but I have tried to search for as much answers as possible.

Comment: What does your C++ textbook say about this subject matter?

Comment: If you want to read text you can't read it using an `int`

Comment: You mean the actual string `"stop"` or is `stop` a special numeric value?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in my text book

Comment: Yes an actual stop string.

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = 0;

std::string aLine;

bool bFoundStop(false);

while (getline(inFile, aLine) && !bFoundStop)
{
    //the basic adding up of the numbers

    if(aLine == "stop")
    {
        bFoundStop = true;
    }
    else    
    {
        int x = atoi(aLine.c_str());
        sum += x;
    }

    std::cout<<sum<<std::endl;
}
inFile.close();
```